# FXLauncher - Is it possible to change/update the JRE after installation

Tags: java, javafx

I have a Self contained JavaFX application installed on windows bundled using FXLauncher.FXLauncher provides auto updates and install new versions from the respository on every application launch but my question is it possible to change/update the JRE that is installed without re-installing the application again ?

Answer (score 0):

According to author [here](https://github.com/edvin/fxlauncher/issues/24) this feature is scheduled for release 2.0.